# How to count the number of Years between two dates

Tags: excel, vba, date, time, offset

This macro counts the number of years between the first and last date of a work experience. I made this work but getting this number in a weird format (Like a Date instead of a number). Looks like that something might be wrong.
Thanks in advance for your comments.

```
Sub CuentaExperiencia()
Worksheets("Candidatos").Activate
'esta macro contabiliza los años de experiencia sumados

Range("T2").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -18).Value = ""
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = DateDiff("d", (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)), (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)))
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Range("AE2").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -29).Value = ""
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = DateDiff("d", (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)), (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)))
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Range("AP2").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -40).Value = ""
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = DateDiff("d", (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)), (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)))
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Range("BA2").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -51).Value = ""
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = DateDiff("d", (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)), (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)))
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Change the cell format to `General`

Comment: Also you are returning the days with `"d"` change it to `"y"` for years.

Comment: paste this number into a cell `43000.8067708333` then change the cell format to `date`, then change the cell format to `time` ... date and time are actually stored as a number.  .... the whole number portion (43000) is the date.  the decimal portion is the time of day

Comment: Also you can use the DATEDIF formula in the sheets: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `=DAYS(end_date,start_date)` formula, and then divide by 365 to get the number of years; no need to use VBA. If you are doing it as part of a larger VBA macro, you can just use `WorksheetFunction.Days(end_date,start_date)`.

EDIT: Even easier: just use `=YEARFRAC()`. It'll do it all for you.

You should note that simply dividing by 365 does not account for leap years, which introduces some error into the answer. While this error is trivial in this case, you may avoid it simply by using `=YEARFRAC(start_date, end_date, [basis])`, and using `1` as the basis parameter. This will force the use of actual calendar days, which will account for leap year correctly. Otherwise, `YEARFRAC` assumes a standard 30-day month for every month, and your answer will be increasingly inexact.

Comment: dividing by 365 can give an inaccurate result because of leap days (february 29)

Comment: Being off by `1/365` of a year shouldn't matter in determining years of work experience.

Comment: (a) It's `=DAYS(end_date,start_date)` (i.e. your parameters are back to front) (b) If you are going to the trouble of using the DAYS function (rather than just calculating `=end_date-start_date`) then you are obviously concerned about the effect on the result caused by the time portion of the two parameters, so that will mean the use of `365` (or even `365.2425`) in the divisor could cause issues.

Comment: @Chilangosta, if you start on march 1st and add 365 days, you can land on march 1st most of the time, but you can also land on february 29th. that is an difference of one year 25% of the time if you are counting whole calendar years  ...  upvote for `=YEARFRAC()`

Comment: @YowE3K (a) thank you; I've adjusted my response accordingly. Incidentally, other date formulas like `YEARFRAC` or VBA's DatedIf use the reverse. (b) DAYS makes sure you end up with a number and not a Date format in default Excel. For example, `=TODAY()-"1/1/2015"` by default returns `9/21/1902` in my Excel.

@jsotola You are absolutely right. If you're concerned with figuring out exact dates, or your margin of error is less than one day every four years, that is a problem.

Comment: Re (b) Yeah, Excel sometimes isn't very intelligent when guessing what cell format to apply.  When it recognises that the formula is subtracting two dates, it usually assumes that it is getting a number back and formats it as `General`.  So, for instance, `=TODAY()-DATE(2015,1,1)` (i.e. using a date instead of a string for the subtracted value) displays 995.  So does `=A1-B1` where both cells are formatted as dates.  But `=TODAY()-A1` would display the result as a date, despite both values being discernible as dates.  Weird Excel.  Silly Excel.  (But we still love it.)

Comment: @YowE3K Sure, that's the Excel we know and love ;) Yeah, because formatting was an issue in OP I just figured he'd rather not deal. Thank you for fixing the YEARFRAC parameters for me BTW.

Comment: Although 1/365 might not make much of a difference in determining work experience for some purposes, it could make an important difference to the employee if used to determine the date of a pay rate change, or any other change based on years of service.  In many contracts, that's usually pretty specific and tied to exact calculations.

Comment: @ron as I've said, that is completely true. However, this seemed to do what OP wanted, while solving the problem of the date format as well.

Comment: Yes, you did, and it probably does since he flagged it as the answer. And I, too, like the answer for its simplicity. However, one of the purposes of SO is to create a repository of good answers, that can be found by searching. I am concerned that an unsophisticated user might do a search on this topic, and utilize your answer without being aware that the result may be somewhat imprecise. I would encourage you to include a brief discussion along these lines in your answer, as opposed to leaving it in the comments.

Comment: @ron thank you for your feedback. I've added some additional information about adjusting for leap years in my answer. How does that look?

Comment: @Chilangosta Thumbs Up

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use Datediff function like this...

```
DateDiff("yyyy", StartDate, EndDate)
```

Sample code:

```
Sub NumberOfYears()
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim Years As Integer

StartDate = #1/1/2015#
EndDate = #12/31/2017#

Years = DateDiff("yyyy", StartDate, EndDate)
MsgBox Years
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA `DateDiff` with "yyyy" can NOT be used to calculate the number of 365-day-differences between two dates! Example: When comparing December 31th to January 1st of the immediately succeeding year, it returns 1, even though only a single day has elapsed, confirms [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function).